# Why LeackCanary provides encrypted method names?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, report, leakcanary

Using LeakCanary library in the statement of a memory leak I get encrypted method names. For example:

```
static hk.o
references ht.a 
leaks Activity instance
```

Can anybody explain this report? Why it not write the names of the methods that I use?

I use the debug version of the code without Proguard.

Comment: The leak may come from the codes that is Proguarded

Comment: If you are testing code that has been obfuscated, then you typically won't be able to get the original class and method names for the obfuscated code.  That is the point of obfuscation.

Comment: I use the debug version of the code without Proguard.

Answer (score 0):

I (probably) had the same problem. Are you using AdMob/Firebase NativeExpressAdView?

If so, pause and destroy the NativeExpressAdView instances before leaving the activity:

```
@Overrride
protected void onDestroy() {
    mAdView.pause();
    mAdView.destroy();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```